# Changing a value in SQLite3

Tags: sql, sqlite, sql-update

I'll start off by showing the code:

```
create table products ('name' text primary key, 'price' INTEGER)
insert into table products ('name', 'price') values ('coke', 8)
insert into table products ('name', 'price') values ('sprite', 9)
```

What would be the SQLite3 code to change the value of the price column for the coke row to 12.
So I want the output to be  coke 12   sprite 9.

Thanks alot guys!

Answer (score 37, accepted):

```
UPDATE products 
   SET price = 12 
 WHERE name = 'coke' AND price = 8;
```

These might just be transcription errors or typos, but you should remove the word `table` from your `INSERT` statements, and you don't need single-quotes around column names, so the statement should look like:

```
insert into products (name, price) values ('sprite', 9)
```