# Beginner problem with SQLite UPDATE statement

Tags: iphone, sqlite

****Please flag as unnecessary-The question no longer relates to the answer.****

I need help changing a single "cell" in a SQLite database.  It's 0, it needs to be 1.  (Yes, I'm using ints as bools).  I believe the problem is in the update.

+favStmt is set to nil earlier.

+gameID is the primary key column.

+useGameID passes in the primary key for the row I want to update.

+isFavorite is the column I want to update.

```
- (void) addFavorite:(NSInteger) useGameID{


if(favStmt==nil){
    const char *sql = "update GameTable Set isFavorite = ? Where gameID=?";
    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &favStmt, NULL) !=SQLITE_OK)
        NSAssert1(0,@"Error while creating favorite stmt. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));

}
sqlite3_bind_int(favStmt, 1, 1);
sqlite3_bind_int(favStmt, 2, useGameID);

if (SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(favStmt))
    NSAssert1(0, @"Error while favoriting. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));


sqlite3_reset(favStmt);
```

}

I found a similar question, but I couldn't figure it out for my purpose.
[Changing a value in SQLite3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4686376/changing-a-value-in-sqlite3)

Thank you for anything!

And for those who say only masochists use straight SQLite, two things.  One, yes, I'm a masochist. Two, I only need this last statement and I should be done with direct SQLite.

Comment: Don't apologize for using integers for booleans in SQLite, that's the [official way to represent booleans](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#boolean).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a real answer, or at least a better one.

Your [`sqlite3_prepare_v2`](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/prepare.html), [`sqlite3_bind_int`](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html), [`sqlite3_step`](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/step.html), [`sqlite3_reset`](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/reset.html) sequence looks correct but I think you're giving `sqlite3_bind_int` the wrong arguments. The arguments for `sqlite3_bind_int` are supposed to be:

1. The statement handle.
2. The the index of the SQL parameter to be set where indexes start at one.
3. The value to bind.

So I think your bind should look like this:

```
sqlite3_bind_int(favStmt, 1, 4);
```

And there's no reason to apologize for occasionally using low level interfaces either, it is useful to know what's going on underneath all the usual pleasantries sometimes. Just don't make a habit of trying to write everything in assembler so to speak :)

Comment: Simply adding that doesn't work :( Isn't sqlite3_step called in the if statement right after the bind? Also, wouldn't this code still not know what to do with useGameID?  Thanks!

Comment: @Jesse: Sorry about all the confusion. I missed your `sqlite3_step` call on my first reading but I see it now. But, I think your bind parameters are wrong so have a look at my updated answer and let me know how it goes.

Comment: @mu is too short, I disagree.  I want the 4th column to be set to 1, so I am following the argument sequence.  You have made me realize I was trying to change the wrong column (I forgot that it starts at 1, not 0), but correcting for that still doesn't work.  The statement has to be the incorrect part of my code.

Comment: @Jesse: "The second argument is the index of the SQL parameter to be set. The leftmost SQL parameter has an index of 1." The second argument refers to *parameter* number, not *column* number and you only have one parameter regardless of how many columns are involved. And columns are inherently unordered in SQL so referring to "column 4" doesn't make sense unless you have an explicit column list to provide an ordering.

Comment: @mu is too short: Ah.  Thanks.  That makes things clearer.  I updated the question to reflect that fix.  However, it's still not working properly.  See updated question.  Thanks!

Comment: At this point, I think it's correct.  I realized I'm not checking if it's changed properly.  I'll mark the question answered as soon as I fix that issue (which is not represented in the code shown).